# How do I pass an array of integer into spring controller?

Tags: java, jquery, spring

script `Array` of `int` and I wish to pass into `Spring Controller`. but I keep getting

```
400 bad request.
```

if my `js array` is

```
array = [1,2,3,4]
array -> 400 bad request
JSON.Stringify(array) -> I will get [1,2,3,4]

    $.ajax({//jquery ajax
                data:{"images": array},                
                dataType:'json',
                type:"post",
                url:"hellomotto"
                ....
            })
```

when I loop the `string List`.. the first element will be `'[1'`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hellomotto", method = Request.POST)
public void hellomotto(@RequestParam("images") List<String> images){
 sysout(images); -> I will get [1,2,3,4]
}
```

public void

May I know how can I do this properly? I have tried different combination

Comment: Please show what you're trying to pass it to and the stack trace from the server.

Comment: the development com is disconnected from internet.. I'm merely trying to pass an array of String/integer into the controller.

Comment: can you share the controller method?

Comment: Whether you're running on an Internet-connected computer is irrelevant; you're running an embedded Web server that just happens to be accessible to only one client, and it has stack traces that explain what failed.

Comment: Also, `array -> 400 bad request` is not very informative. Are you saying that you get that answer if you pass the array into that JQuery AJAX call?

Comment: the first element is not `[1` the `[]` is used to denote that the value is a collection... if you iterate through the collection you can find that the first element is `1`

Comment: when I iterate, I get  '[1' as the first element. That is also partly because JSON.stringify(array), but if I pass in the array by itself.. I will get a 400 bad request(no exception behind)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following is a working example:

Javascript:

```
$('#btn_confirm').click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();     // do not submit the form

    // prepare the array
    var data = table.rows('.selected').data();
    var ids = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
        ids.push(Number(data[i][0]));
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "?confirm",
        data: JSON.stringify(ids),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        },
        failure: function(errMsg) {
            alert(errMsg);
        }
    });
});
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(params = "confirm", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody int confirm(@RequestBody Long[] ids) {
    // code to handle request
    return ids.length;
}
```

Comment: any idea how to do in angular 2, as it is passing array within array.

Answer (score 0):

@RequestParam is used to bind request parameters, so if you do something like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hellomotto", method = Request.POST)
public void hellomotto(@RequestParam("image") String image){
     ...
}
```

and you do post to /hellomotto?image=test, the image variable in hellomotto method will contain "test"

What you want to do is to parse Request body , so you should you should use @RequestBody annotation :

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestbody

it is using jackson labrary (so you will have to include it as your dependency) to parse json object into java object.

Answer (score 0):

I think you wantAjax call,through ajax, you are sending List of Integers
so in spring your controller will be

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hellomotto", method = Request.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void hellomotto(@RequestParam("images") List<Integer> images){
 sysout(images); -> I will get [1,2,3,4]
}
```

***@ResponseBody** is missing in Your Code