# Post array by ajax to Spring boot controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

my ajax function called as

```
    $.ajax({
            url:'${pageContext.request.contextPath}'+'/admin/sendMsg',
            method:'POST',
            traditional: true,
            data:{
                driverList: JSON.stringify(drivers),
                constList: JSON.stringify(constIds),
                content: content
            },
            success: function(data) {
                        if (data == "FAIL") {
                            alert("File not found!");
                        } 
                    },
                    error: function(request, status, error) {
                        alert("The request failed: " + request.responseText);
                    }
        });
```

Where variable "drivers" and "constIds" are array object, output by browser console like

```
["0", "31", "30"]
0: "0"
1: "31"
2: "30"
length: 3__proto__: Array(0)
```

My controller:

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/sendMsg", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void sendMsg(HttpSession session,
            @RequestParam(value = "driverList")String[] driverList,
            @RequestParam(value = "constList")String[] constList, @RequestParam(value = "content")String content)
{
    for (String data : driverList) {
         System.out.println("Your Data =>" + data);
    }
    System.out.println(constList);

}
```

But the output is

```
Your Data =>["0"
Your Data =>"31"
Your Data =>"30"]
```

So how can I get rid of those brackets, then I can parse the string to Integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brackets are appearing because you are calling `JSON.stringify` on the arrays, which is unnecessary. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/sendMsg',
  method: 'POST',
  traditional: true,
  data: {
    driverList: drivers,
    constList: constIds,
    content: content
  },
  success: function(data) {
    if (data == "FAIL") {
      alert("File not found!");
    } 
  },
  error: function(request, status, error) {
    alert("The request failed: " + request.responseText);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a list of errors, attaching below the final working code..

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    headers: { //Required to avoid 415 error
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
    },
    url: "/item/refresh",
    data: JSON.stringify(itemIDs), //itemIDs = ["5", "3", "8"]
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    },
    failure: function(errMsg) {
        alert(errMsg);
    }
});
```

and at Controller side :

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(path = "/item/refresh", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String BookingItemList(@RequestBody Long[] itemIDs) //RequestBody instead of regular parameter
```

References :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11549679/557968
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32970230/557968